Convert loop to mathematical expression
I know that similar questions have been asked before on this forum. Unfortunately, I didn't quite understand the solutions. Many suggest using matrices, that I am not too familiar with. If the answer is same, please close this as duplicate.
My loop is
S=S0 ; Initial value of sum, a variable
Repeat (n) ; number of times to repeat, another variable
{
S = (S + n)/(1- S n)
}

I know that Mathematica supports loops without needing a closed form mathematical expression. But I want to express this in a multivariable sum/product form mathematically, which I then want to use in Mathematica for further processing.
Sorry, I don't have anything to list in the way of "my attempt". I will accept if that is a reason for closing this.

Is $n$ fixed, or does it increment by $1$ each loop?

Fixed, doesn't increment.

See Mobius transformations

Calculation of $4$-th term gives $\dfrac{S_0+4n-6n^2S_0-4n^3+n^4S_0}{1-4nS_0-6n^2+4n^3S_0+n^4}$ and we can clearly see an $1,4,6,4,1$ pattern of Pascal triangle (I checked more terms, the pattern seems to hold). Though $S_0$ is not powered and signs are not alternated either, so it's not gonna be some simple $(n-S_0)^k$. It may be difficult to express it nicely.

Maybe iterated tangent is the way to go as this looks like $\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan a+\tan b}{1-\tan a\tan b}$, so something in the line of $\tan(a+nb)$ for the last term.

@zwim, I am precisely trying to do $\sum 2k \tan^{-1}(2k)$
, which has only closed form in terms of polylog functions. I understand that the formula works MOD π
, but I wanted to at least get that

A rather simple explanation can be given using complex numbers :
Recurrence
$$S_{n+1} = \frac{S_n + n}{1- n S_n}\tag{1}$$
when considered with
$S_n:=\frac{N_{n}}{D_{n}}\tag{2}$
can be written, with appropriate simplifications :
$$\frac{N_{n+1}}{D_{n+1}} = \frac{N_n + n D_n }{D_n- n N_n}\tag{3}$$
otherwise said under a vector description :
$$\binom{N_{n+1}}{D_{n+1}} \cong \binom{N_n + n D_n }{D_n- n N_n}\tag{4}$$
where $\cong$ means "up to a factor".
(4) can be "realized" by the following sequence of complex numbers defined iteratively by :
$$\underbrace{N_{n+1}+iD_{n+1}}_{z_{n+1}}=(1-ni)\underbrace{(N_{n}+iD_{n})}_{z_{n}}\tag{5}$$
(proof by expansion of (5) and identification of the real and imaginary parts) with the correspondence : $$S_n \leftrightarrow \frac{\Im(z_n)}{\Re(z_n)}=\tan{\operatorname{arg}(z_n)}\tag{6}$$
This explains the connection with the sum of $\arctan$ remarked by @zwim (see explanation below) because, taking the arguments on each side of equation (5), and setting, one gets :
$$\theta_{n+1}=\theta_{n}+\arctan{n}$$
where $\theta_n:=\operatorname{arg}(z_n)$

Fig. 1 : Sequence $(z_n)$ has a spiraling behaviour. Roughly speaking, because $\arctan(n) \cong \frac{\pi}{2}$ for large $n$, $z_n$ switches from a quadrant to the previous one at each step.
An alternative explanation (giving a heuristic way to understand (5)) :
(4) can be expressed under a Möbius matrix form :
$$\pmatrix{N_{n+1}\\D_{n+1}} = \pmatrix{1&n\\-n&1}\pmatrix{N_{n}\\D_{n}} \tag{7}$$
(recall : $\cong$ means "up to a factor").
But the matrix involved in (7) can be written under the form
$$\pmatrix{1&n\\-n&1}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}-n\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$$
where the first and second matrix are classicaly associated resp. with $1$ and $i$.

This is neat, thanks !

Thanks for all your efforts to make sure the medicine reaches the patient :) I am familiar with complex numbers and I could understand your explanation better this time. As I mentioned to zwim in my comments, my main aim was to express $\sum 2k \tan^{-1}(2k)$ (with the understanding that it is MOD $\pi$). With your matrix notation now better accessible to me, am I right in expressing it as $\begin{pmatrix}Num(\sum 2k \tan^{-1}(2k)) \ Den(\sum 2k \tan^{-1}(2k)) \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \ 0 \end{pmatrix} . \prod\limits_{j=1}^{M} {\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2j \ -2j & 1 \end{pmatrix}}^{2j}$ ?

If my matrix expression is right, I can also express it as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{M} 2k \tan^{-1}(2k) = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{M}(1-2 i k)^{2k} + \prod\limits_{k=1}^{M}(1+2 i k)^{2k}}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{M}(1-2 i k)^{2k} - \prod\limits_{k=1}^{M}(1+2 i k)^{2k}} \right)$ (MOD $\pi$).
Maybe I am completely off. But that's all I have progressed in my understanding. My even bigger goal is to express this as a series limit in terms of $M$ as $M \to \infty$ without involving polylog functions, but playing with mathematica, I am already seeing signs of that  to my disappointment.

The right matrix product is $ \Pi_{j=1}^{M} \pmatrix{1 & j \ -j & 1}$ without the $2$ and without an exponent on the matrices.

My (end goal) expression is $\sum2k \tan^{-1}(2k) = 2 \tan^{-1}(2) + 4 \tan^{-1}(4) + ... $  Just to get $2 \tan^{-1}(2)$, I have to invoke your eqn7 2 times (with n=2 in eqn7). Similarly for $4 \tan^{-1}(4)$, I have to invoke eqn7 4 times(with n=4 in eqn7) and so on... Anyway, let me re-read your reply multiple times and get back to you with a better framed doubt. Thanks for the help.

My understanding of your recursion is
$$S_{n,k+1} = \frac{S_{n,k} + n}{1 - n S_{n,k}}, \quad k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}. \tag{1}$$
This is directly implemented in Mathematica as
s[n_] := Nest[(# + n)/(1 - n #)&, s[0], n]

Note that this computes only the terminal element of the recursion in $(1)$, i.e., $S_{n,n}$ for a given integer $n \ge 1$.  If you want the full list of iterates, this is done by simply changing Nest to NestList.
We can use the code to compute the first few terms of $S_{n,n}$ and use FullSimplify to conclude that $$S_{n,n} = \frac{a(n) S_0 + b(n)}{a(n) - b(n) S_0} \tag{2}$$ where
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
n & a(n) & b(n) \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & -4 \\
3 & 13 & 9 \\
4 & 161 & -240 \\
5 & 719 & 475 \\
6 & 27755 & -42372 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{array}$$
At this point is where I will stop further analysis, since it is not confirmed that my understanding is correct.

Thanks heropup. Your understanding of my recursion is correct. I looked up your a and b on oeis, but no luck. I will try playing with this in Mathematica

@Srini My advice is to consider the sequence of intermediate terms, not just the terminal one.  You can extract the coefficients by changing Nest to NestList as described above, then entering for example FullSimplify[s[5]] to compute $S_{5,k}$ for $k \in {0, \ldots, 5}$, then entering Transpose[CoefficientList[Numerator[#], s0]& /@ %.

I just tried your code. It gives evaluated numbers (for every iteration or the terminal one). What's the trick to get it symbolic, like the one from zwim in the comments on my main question.
